# How to add two listview in scrollview

Tags: android, listview, layout, scrollview

I am adding  two list view in one scroll view, as my both listview(s) will contains data, but the problem I am facing is that when I add listview(S) in scroll view, it only shows one item of each list view.

Here is the image,

[image]

The XML code is :

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layoutFooter7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linArrange" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linListViews"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lstviewUnBlockVenues"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:divider="#00000000"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false" >

            </ListView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lstviewUnBlockVenues"
                android:background="#ABCDEF"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Blocked Venues"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#061218" />
            </LinearLayout>



            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lstviewBlockedVenues"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:divider="#00000000"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false" >

            </ListView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

All I want is that scroll view should scroll down if the list view contains more items, as at this moment both list views are displaying one item only :(

Comment: The ListView is showing correct data, where's the problem?

Answer (score 6):

I used "arnp" 's answer and made and example with 3 listView in scrollview. It works fine.

layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:background="#ff0000" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:background="#ff0000" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:background="#ff0000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity :

```
package com.example.listviewtest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        ListView list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
        ListView list3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list3);


        String[] items1 = { "Alfa1", "Alfa2", "Alfa3", "Alfa4", "Alfa5", "Alfa6", "Alfa7", "Alfa8", "Alfa9", "Alfa10", "Alfa11", "Alfa12", "Alfa13", "Alfa14", "Alfa15", "Alfa16", "Alfa17"  };
        String[] items2 = { "Beta1", "Beta2", "Beta3", "Beta4", "Beta5", "Beta6", "Beta7", "Beta8", "Beta9", "Beta10", "Beta11", "Beta12", "Beta13", "Beta14", "Beta15", "Beta16", "Beta17" };
        String[] items3 = { "Teta1", "Teta2", "Teta3", "Teta4", "Teta5", "Teta6", "Teta7", "Teta8", "Teta9", "Teta10", "Teta11", "Teta12", "Teta13", "Teta14", "Teta15", "Teta16", "Teta17" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items1);
        list1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items2);
        list2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items3);
        list3.setAdapter(adapter3);

        setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(list1);
        setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(list2);
        setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(list3);

    }

     public void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
         ArrayAdapter listAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) listView.getAdapter(); 
            if (listAdapter == null) {
                // pre-condition
                return;
            }

            int totalHeight = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
                listItem.measure(0, 0);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
            listView.requestLayout();
        }


}
```

Comment: You can also add: ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
to setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren in order to make the adapter generic

Answer (score 1):

Try using a **LinearLayout** and **weight**. Your problem is wrap_content won't make the ListViews fill 50% of the screen.

Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linListViews"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstviewUnBlockVenues"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight= "1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false" >

    </ListView>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstviewBlockedVenues"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false" >

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's best you modify your UI.

Placing one scrolling widget in another in Android really creates lot of problems. There is a workaround but that makes scrolling a pain for the user.

For more information you may click on any of the results that show up on the [google search](https://www.google.com/search?aq=1&oq=listview%20in%20sc&ix=seb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=listview%20in%20scrollview)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a tutorial on the best way is to use [ExpandableListView here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)